# Get same topological Order of Trajan strong component algorithm and standard topological sort

Tags: algorithm, directed-acyclic-graphs, topological-sort, tarjans-algorithm

I am currently working on a challange for college, where I have to get the topological sorting(if its a DAG) of a directed graph(no loops, no multiple edges) or get the strong components(if it is not a DAG). Tarjans algorithm seems to be the best because it finds all the strong components of a graph in reversed topological order. If the graph is a DAG, it finds a reversed topological sort of all the vertices, because every vertex in a DAG is its own SCC. The problem is that the topological sort of tarjans alg. on a DAG doesnt always fit the the one the standard top. sort(the one at the end of the question) finds, which lets all the tests given by my college fail.

One example of this would be this DAG with 8 vertices and the following edges
In this example the stand. top. sorting alg. doesnt create the same top. sort as the tarjan alg.

0 -> 4

1 -> 6

2 -> 1

3 -> 1

5 -> 6

6 -> 4

7 -> 3

The question is if it is possible to always get the topological sorting standard top. sort returns from a modified tarjan and how that modification might look. Tarjans O(v+e) shouldnt be changed by being modified.

I know that i could just implement both, but the challange is about performance, so i would much rather have one algorithm who does both.

I'm currently using tarjans implementation on wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm

this is the stand. top sorting algorithm used for the tests given by my university

```
List L
foreach v ∈ V
    count[v] ← 0
foreach v ∈ V
    foreach Kante (v, w) ∈ E
        count[w] ← count[w]+1
foreach v ∈ V
    if count[v] = 0
       Add v at beginning of L
while L is not empty
    v ← first element in L
    delete v from L
    print v(or assign v and incrementing index)
    foreach Kante (v, w) ∈ E
        count[w] ← count[w]−1
        if count[w] = 0
            add w at the beginning of L
```

This algorith always starts at Vertex 0.
When looking for adj. Vertices it always takes the lowest adj. Vertex(as a number) first. f.e. it would go for 0 ->1 and then 0->6

I hope you can help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by the "standard topological sort?"

Comment: The topological sort at the end of the post

Comment: I'm a bit confused here because that reference algorithm assumes you have some fixed ordering to the nodes and edges in the graph and that the graph is a DAG, neither of which is true for the problem you're trying to solve. What's the expected order of the SCCs you find? (This sounds like either there's some extra information or that this is a poorly-designed problem.)

Comment: The order of the SCC should resemble a reversed topological sort. So if it is a DAG it will find the reversed top. sort of the algorithm at the end of the question

Comment: Yes it assumes that
it always starts with the vertex 0(represented in an array as arr[0])
and the edge (v,w) goes through starting with the lowest w(the order here is given by the array)

Comment: But what happens if there are multiple source nodes in the SCC graph? Which should you pick first?

Comment: Its about changing the tarjan scc algorithm to produce the same topological sorting as the algorithm at the end, if we have DAG(in this case every vertex is in its own SCC, as far as I understand). 
If we dont have a DAG it should just find the SCC. These SCC will have a topological sorting, but wont need to be sorted in the same way as the algorithm at the bottom of my question(This algorithm is given by my university.) I want to implement tarjan to produce the same topological sorting if its a DAG, while still finding all the SCC if it isnt a DAG

Comment: I guess what I'm getting at is that when you form the SCC graph, depending on how you number those SCCs, you'll get back different results when then running the other topological sorting algorithm, especially if there are ties that need to be broken. As a result, I'm not sure there's a clearly correct way to do this without knowing how you're supposed to break ties between indistinguishable SCCs.

Comment: You are right there are no clear rules for how to break the ties.... except the top. sorting algorithm they gave us, which isnt really helpful. i guess.